# Sync google calendar with iphone cal through coding..?

Tags: iphone, calendar

I want to make an app...that can sync my iphone calender with google calendar..i want to do it through coding....

Comment: Hey I want to implement same thing if u have knowledge abt it please explain it to me and from where i can start coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Have a look at the [Google Calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/).

You'll also want to have a look at [CalDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV).

And have a look at [How to Sync Google Calendar With iPhone Calendar](http://www.iphonedownloadblog.com/2009/06/30/how-to-sync-google-calendar-with-iphone-calendar/) for tips.

Comment: I have tried all these links but i am not able to find the info i need..i want code that can update the events from google cal to iphone cal...
i had tried this app
http://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcal/
but this will show the events in gooogle cal in table view..can you tell me how i can add these events to iphone cal (or synchronize)..i am trying it on simulator..can we open iphone native calendar in simulator..??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Gdata](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/index.html), Googles API for their services, which is available in objective-c

Comment: yes i tried...this...but i think with this we can make an app that can show the list of events at google cal...but i need a code to add these events to the iphone cal..(means synchronizing)...??any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone cal can automatically sync with your google cal - don't follow how or why you'd do it with coding?